# How to memset the OVERLAPPED structure?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am currrently doing something like this

```
OVERLAPPED* oarray = new OVERLAPPED[100];
```

How do I make sure that all the OVERLAPPED in the array have the member variable hEvent = nullptr
Is there a way to memset the OVERLAPPED structure so that hEvent is null in each ? I know I can do this via a for loop but wanted to know if there is a better way ?

Comment: memset (oarray, 0, sizeof (oarray));

Comment: @Mike I think you are incorrect. It should be memset(oarray, 0, 100*sizeof(OVERLAPPED)). Not sure though

Comment: Both work. sizeof (array) = total size, sizeof (array [0]) = element size. It means that changing the type/size/dimensions of the structure does not affect the code.

Comment: @Mike `oarray` is a pointer here, not an array, so `sizeof(oarray)` will give you the size of a pointer.